# Zyxel NSA325 Drive error

Tags: hard-drive, nas, raid-1, smart

I have a Zyxel NSA325 NAS at home with two 3TB WD REDs in it. I've noticed last week that the led indicator on the front for the second drive is red, I've checked the manual and it says:

> Red means that the NSA detected an error on the hard drive (like a bad sector for example). TheNSA automatically tries to recover a bad sector, but the LED stays red until the NSA restarts. Evenif the hard drive still functions, it is recommended that you replace it since errors are a sign that thehard drive may fail soon.

I restarted the NAS and it was green again. Since then it happened again.
I've checked the logs but found nothing, also the SMART tells me that everything is okay (I'm just a simple user though, so I can't really tell).
Here is the SMART summary for both of the drives:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12wHF5kaZNrRZCeLWncY7b__0JDLUX1ck8Rpb4nzlTOE/edit?usp=sharing

Can you guys help me out what should I do with it? The drives are in RAID 1 so loosing data shouldn't be that probable. But should I buy a new disk and replace the "bad" one immediately? Should I even worry about this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The results you've posted show that both drives have Pre-fail status for the Reallocated Sector count, which is not a very good. These basically are invisible bad sectors that have been swapped with reserve sectors and issues could occur if their number starts to grow because the sectors available for replacement are limited.

So what I'd suggest is to run an additional test with [Data Lifeguard Diagnostics](http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en), which is the manufacturer tool and therefore is tuned to the specific firmware of the drives, and see what the results will be.

Once the test is complete feel free to upload some screenshots so I can take a look. :)

Comment: Are you sure about that? I mean the entries are there but the raw value is 0, so based on what I've read it's nothing.

Comment: It might be nothing indeed, but nonetheless a second test won't harm and it will be good to see what the software has to say about the HDDs health. Furthermore, if you run an Extended test the software will try to fix automatically any kind of software errors it finds, including the one reported already (although for shortly).

Comment: Is it possible to run such a test on the NAS? I've found a scan function which I ran last week, and as I remember it said it fixed something (don't remember though what was it exactly) The problem is that I don't have a desktop computer, only a macbook pro

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way : HirensBootCd Download
Download ISO, put on a USB stick.
Take out faulty drive, connect to a desktop, then boot from HIRENS.

Go into Mini Win XP, in there open HBCD menu, search for DISK tools -> Victoria / HDDScan do a full Drive scan. (read scan)

Then you will see how bad it is. Depending how bad it is you can re-map bad sectors through Victoria ( i prefer this way ) or :

If there are Baddies depends what kind of Baddies, if Logical then no problems, just Do low-level format, if Physical bad block, then u need to do under windows CHKDSK C: /R (where C: is your drive letter)
Let it run and it will REMAP the drive :)

If you are running RAID,0 or smthing, you need to re-map both harddrives etc.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a desktop machine, only a macbook pro. Is it possible to run something like this on the NAS easily?